# mongod, mac os x - rlimits warning

Tags: macos, mongodb, limits

I've been using mongo on my mac os x 10.8 and suddenly yesterday at my logs appeared this warning (and when starting shell it's present too) -

> WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

Who could explain, what does it mean? And should I increase number of **rlimits** somehow?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/261023/how-to-change-default-ulimit-values-in-mac-os-x-10-6

Comment: See also http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, but I wonder do I really need to increase them?

Comment: @Kosmetika That would depend on the load. I can't answer for mongod in particular, but databases in general tend to _strongly_ dislike running out of file descriptors.

Comment: In development you should be keep the ulimit quite low. Having a low rlimit / ulimit will help you detect when you're failing to close db connections.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

on mac, you probably using mongodb for development purpose. If yes, then you can ignore this.

Comment: i'm ignoring it, but i'm a bit confused why it didn't appear at the start of using mongodb

Comment: 'rlimit' is related with amount of memory allocated to process. Its os thing. In this case memory allocated to mongod process. So mongodb complaining you that memory allocated is low & it might be slow. I guess thats ok on development machine. But if you reading those on production, you defiantly need to increase that limit.

Comment: just type "ulimit -n 2048" or something higher and it won't complain

Comment: "ulimit -n 2048" has no effect.

Comment: It has for me. You need to call it before starting the server: ulimit -n 2048 && mongod; afterwards you should no longer see the error.

Comment: My dev mongo crashed and lost all my collections during a long intense script run last night. It had been giving me this error. I'm assuming it had to do with the crash. I'm still unsure, but I'd urge people not to ignore this warning.

Comment: In my case, I had to do `ulimit -n 2048` at the **same** terminal tab that I start mongod process. Seems like it needs to be restarted too. Doing it so at the other tabs hadn't worked.

Comment: I used the `ulimit -n 2048` in the same tab and it worked no warnings. It doesn't have to be 2048 it could be anything as long as its bigger than or equal to 1000 you shouldn't get the warning.

Comment: ulimit allocation command for MacOS should be with "-f" not "-n". here is the full command: ulimit -f 2048

Comment: `launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 1024`

Comment: On macos `10.9.4` (developer machine) I just added `ulimit -n 2048` in my `.profile`.

Comment: ulimit -n 2048 && mongod works for me on OSX. Thanks to C.F.

Comment: I am late to the topic but answer [Shell Session Limit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221988)  worked for me pretty well. Little too long to paste into the comment but if you ventured here you should check it out. Problem with `ulimit -n 2048` is that it doesn't persist, os you either need an alias or just follow the link for LaunchDaemons config.

Comment: `launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 1024` might make your system unusable. Use larger numbers: `launchctl limit maxfiles 10000 49152`. Also, check the answer to this post, it was helful to me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366187/why-does-setting-the-hard-limit-for-maxfiles-to-unlimited-using-launchctl-lim/366319