# MongoDB "soft rlimits too low" on FreeBSD

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When opening up a mongo shell I noticed a message that says:

```
Server has startup warnings:
2016-09-06T12:07:03.001-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-06T12:07:03.001-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. 
rlimits set to 12186 processes, 234972 files.
Number of processes should be at least 117486 : 0.5 times number of files.
```

I have looked for solutions to this but all I've found is that [you can ignore this message if it's a development sever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621763/mongod-mac-os-x-rlimits-warning).

But the problem is that this message is **not** on a development server and it appearing on my production system. Is this anything I should be worried about or can I ignore this warning message?

I'm using MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9 on FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the limits for the process in /etc/security/limits.conf; and also, for the change to be persistent you have to edit de init script, for example, in Red Hat 7, the init script has the following line:

```
LimitNOFILE=64000
```

You have to add the next one:

```
LimitNPROC=32000
```

Then restart the service.
I hope this helps.